# how to create caller function that, takes in function as param with its arguments and calls it

Tags: c++

I'd like to create a c++ function which takes in a function as a parameter as well as take variable amount of arguments(if any) and then call the function inside my caller function.
Below is a little example, the reason for doing all of this, i am making a loggingLib, which aims to make debugging cleaner and easier without having to breakpoint things and cout all over the place because its messy, so i've thought of making a function which when set to true. Prints the debug nature that the programmer has defined. And when toggled off, runs the function as normal.
Here is an example of what i have already achieved:[Github Repo](https://github.com/slimjimmyy/LoggingLib)

Any input would help, thank you so much!

```
void Caller(void *func, ...) {
    //above here i'll run my other code

    //then this is called when i am done
    func(...);
}
```

I have tried a version of this function which has not worked out for me at all, I receive errors just all over the place.

Comment: Please provide all relevant info, e.g. your [mre] directly here. Try for [ask].

Comment: [Template parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)?

Comment: @Chris That can be done, I usually rely on the fact that lambdas already can do most of that job (unless there is a very strict need for performance optimization)

Comment: The function already exists and is called `std::invoke`. It doesn't run your other code but you may want to look at [how it works](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) for an inspiration.

Comment: A variadic function as you wrote requires `va_list`, the ellipsis rotation is not correct here. It is VERY unsafe construct  which checks its arguments at run time. It also is limited to arguments of some fundamental types like arythmetic no smaller than `int` and pointers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) (from [`<functional>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional)) with a [**template parameter pack**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) to achieve what you need.
This goes well with [std::forward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to achieve [perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/what-are-the-main-purposes-of-stdforward-and-which-problems-does-it-solve) of the arguments.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename F, typename... Args>
void Caller(F f, Args&& ... args) {

    // Do whatever ...

    // Call f (with perfect forwarding):
    std::invoke(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


void f0() {
    std::cout << "f0" << std::endl;
}

void f1(int a) {
    std::cout << "f1: " << a << std::endl;
}

void f2(int a, float b) {
    std::cout << "f2: " << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    Caller(f0);
    Caller(f1, 1);
    Caller(f2, 1, 2.2f);
}
```

Output:

```
f0
f1: 1
f2: 1, 2.2
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YxM1hE6nG)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! 
That live demo site scared me so much with all that assembly ahahah, this is great, thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help, and you can close the assembly tabs if it's too scary ;-)  Note that that you can click the '✔' mark to accept the answer most suited for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to do if you let lambdas do all the hard work for you.
(Instead of relying on function pointers)

For example :

```
template<typename fn_t>
void caller(fn_t fn)
{
   // do stuff.
   fn();
   // other stuff
}

void my_function(int value)
{
    std::cout << value << "\n"; 
}

int main()
{
   int value{42};
   caller([&]{ my_function(value); });
}
```

Comment: I've got this covered and actually had a working version of this now that i remember. My problem was making it work with parameters, without using a macro definition.

Comment: I updated the example to cover that too ;)

Answer (score 2):

Would this do what you're looking for?

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename F, typename... Ts>
void Decorate(F function, Ts&&... args)
{
    // Some function/callable decoration
    // ...
    //

    std::invoke(function, std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}

void MyFunction(std::string const& msg)
{
    std::cout << msg << "\n";
}

void MyOtherFunction(std::string const& msg, int const value)
{
    std::cout << msg << " " << value << "\n";
}

class MyClass final {
public:
    void SomeMethod(std::string const& msg) const
    {
        std::cout << msg << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Decorate(MyFunction, "Message only");
    Decorate(MyOtherFunction, "Message and a value: ", 5);

    MyClass const instance{};
    Decorate(&MyClass::SomeMethod, instance, "Message from within method to demonstrate utility of std::invoke");
    return 0;
}
```